# Django complex ordering

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a Django model `Document`, which can have `Vote` objects pointing on it. There's a integer field on `Vote` called `score`.

I want to order a queryset of documents according to the number of `Vote` objects with `score=1` that are pointing at the document. i.e., the document that has the most positive votes should be the first one in the queryset.

Is it possible with Django? How?

Comment: I presume you mean `score=1`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Correct, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this (on the `QuerySet` model):

```
def order_by_score(self):
    q = django.db.models.Q(ratings__score=1)
    documents_with_one_positive_rating = self.filter(q) # Annotation sees only
                                                        # the positive ratings
    documents_without_one_positive_rating = self.filter(~q)

    return (documents_with_one_positive_rating |
            documents_without_one_positive_rating).annotate(
                db_score=django.db.models.Count('ratings')
                ).order_by('-db_score')
```

Advantage is it still shows the documents without a positive rating.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for annotations.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Document.objects.filter(score=1).annotate(
             positive_votes=Count('vote__count')).order_by('positive_votes')
```

**Edit**

There isn't really a way to do this without filtering, because that's the way the underlying database operations work. But one not-so-nice way would be to do a separate query for all the documents not included in the original, and chain the two querysets together:

```
positive_docs = <query from above>
other_docs = Document.objects.exclude(id__in=positive_docs)
all_docs = itertools.chain(positive_docs, other_docs)
```

This would work as long as you don't have millions of docs, but would break things like pagination.

Comment: This makes sense, but can we do this without filtering the `Document` objects? I also want to see documents that have no votes.

Comment: Pretty please, with sugar on top?